# Как на javascript вывести несколько копий одного изображения?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня программа для устного счета. Хочу сделать вывод предметов-изображений для счета

У меня есть css spite с изображениями разных предметов и мне надо вывести несколько копий подряд одного изображения (количество генерируется случайным образом).

Возможно есть идея как это сделать оптимальнее, а не так как я себе это представляю.

Comment: покажите то что у вас есть

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сразу приходит на ум простейшая реализация:

```
<div id="image-layout"></div>

function imagesTemplateCreator(elemClassName, count) {
    let images = [];
    let template;
    let imageLayout = document.querySelector('#image-layout');
    imageLayout.innerHTML = "";

    for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {                                 
        images.push('<div class="'+ elemClassName +'">simple-image '+ i +'</div>');
    }                                                       
    template = images.join(' ')
    imageLayout.innerHTML = template;
}

imagesTemplateCreator('simple-class', 33);
```

Можно доработать функцию, если хотите... 
Спрайты накладываются через CSS класс.
К сожалению, данный вариант не сильно будет производителен, если мы захотим показать сразу много картинок, допустим 3000...

Comment: А Вы пробовали запустить код? Мне кажется, что  `join` не сработает, т.к. цикл к тому времени еще не завершится.

Comment: Да, разумеется. https://jsfiddle.net/w885juad/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, этот код у меня заработал. Теперь надо будет подумать как менять параметр background-position, чтобы показывались разные картинки случайным образом.